# I need to code a Chrome Extension that plays a sound when I press the key "e"

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I don't know why this doesn't work. I´m a beginner on this and I would like some answer that let me know what I'm doing wrong

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Maradona",
  "description": "Escuchalo a Maradona",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] },

  "commands": {
    "toggle-feature": {
      "suggested_key": { "default": "E" },
      "description": "Send a 'toggle-feature' event to the extension"
    },


  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage"
  ]
  }
}
```

this is my background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(commands) {
  new Audio("win.mp3").play()
})
```

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Where is `"win.mp3"` located?

Comment: in the folder of the extension

Comment: it says this when I try to upload it "Contents of 'commands[1]' invalid"

Comment: Upload to where?

Comment: to Google Chrome

Comment: Why is the audio file not included within the extension?

Comment: yeah in the extension. the extension folder has 4 items: the icon.png, manifest.json, win.mp3 and background.js

Comment: Why is the audio file not listed within the extension manifest? You can alternatively pass a `data URI` to `new Audio()`

Comment: oh ok! thank you so much! If you know where I can have some examples please let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a [`data URI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) to `new Audio()`

```html
<button>click</button>
<script>
document.querySelector("button")
.onclick = function() {
  new Audio("data:audio/ogg;base64,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").play()
}
</script>
```